# What is the meaning of "behind logging in"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "behind logging in" in this line?

> – So someone inside u.D.S. Is suppressing information.
>
> — No. No, I don't think so. Honestly, I think they're just slow as ass. Ronnie, my idiot supervisor, told me that u.D.S. is **behind logging in** their property acquisitions.

Comment: I have edited your question, hopefully making it easier to read. If my editing is wrong, let me know and I will restore it back to your original.

Comment: This is from the TV show *Manifest* and the script can be found [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=manifest-2018&episode=s01e08). A couple more lines of dialogue before and after what was quoted would have made the context quite clear. Before: "Which also wasn't in the records. That means there's nothing recent in the database." After: "The paperwork's got to be on a desk somewhere in the U.D.S. Records Department."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of "behind" is 'to be late or tardy in doing something', e.g. "I can't go to the party tonight because I am behind in my studies; I have to stay in to try and catch up."

A 'log' is a common name given to a regular or systematic record that is kept for official purposes, eg a ship's log is a record of the places a ship has been, the cargo it has carried, and any important events that have occurred on-board. In this case, it appears that u.D.S. keeps a log of the property that they have acquired. A 'log' can be electronic or paper-based.

'Logging in' can have many meanings, but one of them is to enter data into a 'log'.

The writer in this case is saying that u.D.S. is not deliberately suppressing information about its acquisitions, it is merely tardy in logging those acquisitions onto its property log.